# Is it possible to make that kind of query in solr

Tags: solr

I've get a column in solr - type string which is with values like  'JOHN JACKON', 'JAKE SMITH', 'JOHNATAN JAMESON'

IS it possible to tell solr when I type J to get first these record which has J more times than the other.

Answer (score 0):

You may use solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory. You can set minGramSize to 1.

This FilterFactory is very useful in matching prefix substrings (or suffix substrings if side="back") of particular terms in the index during query time.

Reference: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory

So for your examples above,

for JOHN JACKSON, it will store:

J, JO, JOH, JOHN, J, JA, JAC, JACK, JACKS, JACKSON

and for JAKE SMITH:

j, JA, JAK, JAKE, S, SM, SMI, SMIT, SMITH

Now when someone searches for J, first document(john jackson) will get higher score, because J is twice in the index.